# Daily customizable alarm fires every time app opened

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

In my Android Kotlin app I setup a daily recurring alarm whose receiver pushes a notification message to the user reminding them to do a certain action in the app each day (They can also change the reminder time in settings).

I set this up in the `MainActivity.onCreate` method (because I want a reminder to be set up for all users of the app and this was the only place I could think of that would executed for all):

```kotlin
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Setup the alarm notifications
        setupRepeatingAlarm()
```

This `setupRepeatingAlarm` method takes the following form:

```kotlin
    fun setupRepeatingAlarm(){
        /**
         * Create a periodic alarm
         * If the user has disabled alarms we do nothing
         * If they set a time we schedule for then
         */
        Timber.tag(TAG).d("Setting up the repeating alarm...")
        val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
            applicationContext)

        // What are the user's notification prefs?
        val remindersEnabledKey = applicationContext.getString(R.string.reminders_enabled)
        val reminderHourKey = applicationContext.getString(R.string.reminder_hour)
        val reminderMinuteKey = applicationContext.getString(R.string.reminder_minute)
        val remindersEnabled = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(remindersEnabledKey, false)
        var reminderHour = sharedPreferences.getString(reminderHourKey, "9")
        var reminderMinute = sharedPreferences.getString(reminderMinuteKey, "0")
        if(reminderHour === null){
            reminderHour = "9"
        }
        if(reminderMinute === null){
            reminderMinute = "0"
        }

        if(!remindersEnabled){
            Timber.tag(TAG).d("User does not have reminders enabled")
            return
        } else{
            Timber.tag(TAG).d("Set alarm for $reminderHour:$reminderMinute...")
        }

        val notifyIntent = Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
        val notifyPendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this,
            requestCode,
            notifyIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

        // Ensure we remove any existing notifications
        val notificationManager = ContextCompat.getSystemService(
            this, NotificationManager::class.java
        ) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.cancelNotifications()

        // Set the alarm to start at approximately 9am
        // Then daily at this time
        val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
            set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, reminderHour.toInt())
            set(Calendar.MINUTE, reminderMinute.toInt())
        }
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.timeInMillis,
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
            notifyPendingIntent
        )


    }
```

I used shared preferences to see if this user has reminders enabled and their time pref, then setup `setInexactRepeating` alarm with a `DAILY` interval. This has a pending intent that calls the `AlarmReceiver`. I also do `notificationManager.cancelNotifications()` to try avoid multiple existing.

**The problem**

This seems to result in more than 1 reminder in a given day. Just opening the app seems to line up another notification shortly after, even if I already had several that day and even if my reminder time isn't the current time.

I guess my method is broken and I should not be setting things up like this, but what would be the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would set this up where `setupRepeatingAlarm` isn't called every time `MainActivity` is started. Set it up as an setting/option and only call it when an alarm needs to be set and `NEVER` again until the user sets another alarm. i.e. Have a `button` that shows a view that will allow the user to select an alarm time and when they are done call `setupRepeatingAlarm` with the entered time.